# Advise for comment to my friend's social media which have meat

Tags: commentary

[image]

Today is a holiday, my friend post the dinner on the social media, I want to comment to celebrate their happy life.

But I see the fish and beef in the pictures, I don't know how to comment, because in Buddhism there is banned to eat meat. They are not Buddhist scholars. They are not Buddhist at all.

Comment: Meat is banned in Buddhism, what’s the source ?

Comment: Voting to close this question as it is based on a faulty premise and there are already plenty of questions on this site which deal with meat and Buddhism

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate of existing questions. There are many questions on this site for the topic of vegetarianism and meat-eating. Please see if any of the linked questions answer your question. You can also search the site for many more questions on this topic. Your question is not detailed and focused enough to be different and unique from existing questions on this topic.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You "wanted to comment to celebrate" so why don't you? Did you know they eat meat or did you just discover that from their Facebook post? You say "they're not Buddhist scholars" ... are they Buddhist at all, do you think they want to know (or to be told) about Buddhist doctrine?

Comment: what holiday is it?

Comment: @Letsbuddhism I'd guess https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juneteenth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the Buddhist themselves? And if they are, are they one of the traditions which ban eating of meat for lay people (of which there are a few)? If you yourself don’t eat meat, then when you comment, simply don’t mention the food and rather focus on them.